# Searching if a check boxes value contains something with javascript on PHP

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement, contains

So im trying to check all the checkboxes in my form in which values contain "United Kingdom" (this value does change)

at the moment ive tried creating a function based on some google snippets but no luck, here it is:

```
function checkValue(field, value) {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    if (field.indexOf(value) != -1) {
        field[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

and i call it with a button like this

> OnClick="checkValue(document.form.vote, document.form.countrylist.value)"

its pulling the data from a listbox if that helps

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: so what is the field argument?  ok if answer uses jQuery?

Comment: i would prefer it not to use jquery but if it has to sure just please include the includes because im a skid when it comes to it ^^ thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
function checkValue(field, value) {
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        if (field[i].value.indexOf(value) != -1) {
            field[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i tried that but when pressing the button it ticks all the boxes instead of only ones in witch the value contains "United Kingdom".

Comment: NVM got it working just had to tweak the values of the checkboxes thx :D

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be this?

```
field[i].checked = 'checked'
```

instead of true?  As far as I know 'checked' is the value for the attribute 'checked'.  If this is a dumb answer sorry, I haven't done DOM stuff without jQuery in forever.